# Skype URI any way to set status/mood?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, skype, skype4com

Now that skype will be retiring its desktop API in favor of skype URIs, I am trying to figure out how to modify the status and mood message.  My application is a chrome extension, and people that use it know what it does.  Its a legitimate use case.  Currently its easy with the COM api wrapper on windows and a simple applescript on OS X.  It seems this will become impossible to do once they retire the API.  Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [API reference](http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/reference), sadly there are no methods to affect status/mood in the new API.

It will, indeed, be impossible, as well as porting many other functions exposed to the deprecated skype4com.